# Submitting multiple text fields and files in HTML form with AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Im new to AJAX/JQuery, and I'm wondering if there is a way to send, via an AJAX request, data from an HTML form that includes a text file, and 2 separate text boxes. I have been able to send the data from the text boxes, but the file is not sent.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // this is the id of the form
    $("#SQLsubmit").submit(function() {

        var url = "DAOserv"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : url,
            data : $("#SQLsubmit").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data); // show response from the php script.
            }
        });

        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
</script>
```

This is my AJAX call^

```
<div class="row">
<form id="SQLsubmit" name="SQLsubmit">

    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
        <textarea rows="11" id="BAU" name="BAU" class="form-control"
            placeholder="BAU Reason" form="SQLsubmit"></textarea>
        <input type="file" name="file" /> <input type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-8">
        <textarea rows="11" id="SQL" name="SQL" class="form-control"
            placeholder="SQL Statements" form="SQLsubmit"></textarea>    
    </div>

</form>
```

Here is the HTML.

If anyone could show me how to get the two text files, and the file into my Java Servlet (using the doPOST method), so I am able to parse all into strings, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

edit: The problem I am having when running the code in the original post is that the text fields get sent, but the file is not being sent.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `enctype: 'multipart/form-data`. Otherwise how jquery should know you are sending a file.

This link might help:
[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 $("#SQLsubmit").submit(function() {

     var url = "DAOserv"; // the script where you handle the form input.

     $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         url : url,
         data : new FormData(this),
         success : function(data) {
             alert(data); // show response from the php script.
         }
     });

 return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: Just tried this, and got a 404 error. The problem I am having when running the code in the original post is that the text fields get sent, but the file is not being sent.